# Java: Starting Thread on mouse click event

Tags: java, multithreading

All! :)
I am newbie in Java, so, maybe, my question is little stupid, but...
I am trying to run a Thread by mouse click on JButton.

Here i added a mouse listener:

```
btnGo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
  t.run();
  }
});
```

And my ThreadTest class:

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {   
        System.out.println("Tick!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}

}
```

Thread is starting normally by clicking (i see "Tick-s in console :)" , but main thread with window hangs :(
Цhy is this happening?

Comment: instead of `t.run();` use `t.start();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run() does not start Thread. Try start() instead.

```
btnGo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
  t.start();
  }
});
```

But be aware: You can start Thread only one time!

Maybe it's better to implement interface (not tested, sorry if there any compile errors):

```
public class RunnableTest implements Runnable{

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {   
        System.out.println("Tick!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}

}
```

and then:

```
btnGo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  Thread t = new Thread(new RunnableTest());
  t.start();
  }
});
```

(and maybe you need to stop thread before...)

Answer (score 1):

> Thread is starting normally by clicking (i see "Tick-s in console :)" , but main thread with window hangs :( Цhy is this happening?

In fact the current thread (UI thread here) has entered the `run` method. This thread is responsible for the refresh if your GUI. Since it is busy with "Ticks" messages priting, the window hangs...

Replace this line of cocde:

```
t.run();
```

with this:

```
t.start();
```

Don't forget to find a clean way for exiting the run method. Otherwise your thread will run for ever until the JVM is stopped. You would end up with something like this:

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{
   private boolean canGo=true;    

    public void run()
    {
        while(canGo)
        {   
            System.out.println("Tick!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }

    public void kill() {
        canGo = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Mouse implements MouseListener, Runnable
{
Thread mouseWork;

@Override
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("CRAZY!!!");
        System.out.println("!!!CRAZY");
    }
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    mouseWork = new Thread(this);
    mouseWork.start();
    System.out.println("GO!");
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    mouseWork.stop();
    System.out.println("STOP!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the thread onject

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {   
        System.out.println("Tick!");
        try {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}

}
```